# What date-time format should I use here?

Tags: c#, datetime-format

Here is my string `"Wednesday 15th of April 2020 07:36:46 AM CDT"`.

Here is my code for parsing it:

```cs
var dtf = "dddd d MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss tt zz";

var x = "Wednesday 15th of April 2020 07:36:46 AM CDT"
  .Replace("st ", " ")
  .Replace("th ", " ")
  .Replace(" of ", " ")
  .Trim();

DateTime.ParseExact(x, dtf, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But it does not parse:

> Unhandled exception. System.FormatException: String 'Wednesday 15 April 2020 07:36:46 AM CDT' was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

I think I have the format wrong.

**How can I parse this date-time?**

Comment: You'll have to do this without "CDT".  Timezone abbreviations like that are ambiguous.

Comment: You have two things to deal with outside of the date format: The "th" suffix and the time zone. Neither of those can be handled just with a format. You're going to have to do some preprocessing. You could also remove the "of" before hand or hard-code it in the format - either would work.

Comment: Here are some examples of date formats that should work:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: FYI - since I read it in one of the comments beware of `August` - ends with `st` and you don't want to replace the `st` there.